# How to trigger a certain piece of PHP code or How can I run a php file at a predefined time?

Tags: php, triggers

I need to trigger some codes That perform certain action , or I want to perform those codes with a timing ,ie I want to run a PHP file today 10.00AM .. How it possible ?

Comment: Have a look at cronjobs

Comment: Search Cronjobs (Linux) or Scheduled Tasks (Windows), this should give you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cron the code for 10AM would be:

```
0 10 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is a good site to have a look at: http://crontab-generator.org/

But you will need to learn the basics of setting up the cronjob as there maybe some small differences between distros

Comment: I am using windows server..

Comment: You are looking at Scheduled Tasks on windows, this should be installed already. If you have any problems with the many settings there are tutorials on the web to help search 'Create Scheduled Task' in google.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a linux-based server. Look into cron (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that'll allow you to automate the running of your script.

Comment: How can I test on XAMPP server on windows ?

Comment: On Windows you'd need to use Task Scheduler it's not the prettiest thing to do, but it can work if you're in a pinch, see: http://mukundtopiwala.blogspot.co.nz/2012/07/run-php-script-automatically-on-windows.html

Or you could get a Raspberry Pi (or an old PC) and have a very cheap linux-based development platform that's a lot more similar to any servers you'd pay to use.